# How to override the slice functionality of list in its derived class

Tags: python, list, overriding

I make a class like below:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.list = lst
```

I want slice functionality to be overridden in MyList

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You need to provide custom [`__getitem__()`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__), [`__setitem__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setitem__) and [`__delitem__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__delitem__) hooks.

These are passed a [slice object](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#slice) when slicing the list; these have `start`, `stop` and `step` attributes. However, these values could be `None`, to indicate defaults. Take into account that the defaults actually change when you use a negative stride!

However, they also have a [`slice.indices()` method](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#slice.indices), which when given a length produces a tuple of `(start, stop, step)` values suitable for a `range()` object. This method takes care of such pesky details as slicing with a negative strides and no start or stop indices:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    if isinstance(key, slice):
        indices = range(*key.indices(len(self.list)))
        return [self.list[i] for i in indices]
    return self.list[key]
```

or, for your case:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    return self.list[key]
```

because a `list` can take the `slice` object directly.

In Python 2, [`list.__getslice__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getslice__) is called for slices without a stride (so only start and stop indices) if implemented, and the built-in `list` type implements it so you'd have to override that too; a simple delegation to your `__getitem__` method should do fine:

```
def __getslice__(self, i, j):
    return self.__getitem__(slice(i, j))
```

Comment: **Brilliant answer.** It should be noted, however, that this is... *incomplete.* The `key` passed to `__getitem__()` could also be a `tuple` containing one or more `slice` items, which would need to be handled similarly. The `__setitem__()` and `__delitem__()` dunder methods also need similar generalization, of course. See [this `MultiIndexingList` example](https://riptutorial.com/python/example/1571/indexing-custom-classes----getitem------setitem---and---delitem--) for relevant subclass logic handling all possible edge cases.

Comment: @CecilCurry I specifically focus on how *Python lists* are sliced. Extended slicing is not handled by the standard list type, which is why I left that out.

Answer (score 8):

```
class MyList(list):
    def __init__(self, lst):
        self.list = lst
```

doesn't make much sense... `self` is the list object itself, and it has already been created at this point, maybe you want to override `__new__`, however you probably don't need to touch that. Anyway you want to override `__getitem__` like so:

```
def __getitem__(self, val):
    if isinstance( val, slice):
        # do stuff here
```

Answer (score 1):

As both [@Martijn Pieters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16033058/14041921) and [@jamylak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16033070/14041921) said, you need to implement the `__getitem__` method.

In general, if one wants to override the slicing functionality of it's super class, and keep using super's methods that already uses super's `__getitem__`, just split it into cases, and benefit from both worlds.

For example:

```py
import pandas as pd

class SubFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, slice):
            # your implementation
            print("'My slicing'")
            return SubFrame(super().__getitem__(item))
        else:
            return super().__getitem__(item)
```

Now you can do:

```py
>>> sf = SubFrame({'A': (10,20,30,40,50)})
>>> sf[1:-2]
'My slicing'
    A
1  20
2  30
>>> type(sf[1:-2])
<class '__main__.SubFrame'>
```

And `[]` will still call super's `__getitem__`

```py
>>> sf['A']  # super's __getitem__
0    10
1    20
2    30
3    40
4    50
Name: A, dtype: int64
>>> type(sf['A'])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```