# Zero outside the range of a list / array

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy, scipy

With a Python list

```
L=[1,2,3,4]
```

I would like that `L[m] = 0` if `m` is different to `0,1,2,3`, ie :

```
...
L[-2]=0 
L[-1]=0  
L[0]=1
L[1]=2
L[2]=3
L[3]=4
L[4]=0
L[5]=0
```

and

```
L[-2:2] = [0, 0, 1, 2]
```

This won't work with a classical list or array. What is the **good way** to do this ?

Edit : This is a nice solution (given by one the answer here) :

```
class MyList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return super(MyList, self).__getitem__(index) if index >= 0 and index < len(self) else 0
```

But I'm still unable to have

```
L[-2:2] = [0, 0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Do you mean that assigning outside the bounds of the list (which negative indices won't necessarily do - they start from the end and work backwards) should create new entries? What should happen between the existing list and new entry? Why not just use a dictionary with integer keys?

Comment: So, let me get this straight. You have list `a` and list `b`. What you want to do is change all the elements in list `b` to 0, which are not members of list `a`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Hey Jon! Long time no see. Remember me from Edx? If you've got some time, come over the the Python Chat room.

Comment: How about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574636/getting-a-default-value-on-index-out-of-range-in-python

Comment: I tried to implement the slicing thing with `__getslice__` but the syntax `a[-2:2]` passes the arugments `(2,2)` to `__getslice__` because it doesn't support negative arguments, and I don't know how to override this.

Comment: I looked for documentation on `__getslice__` and found that it is deprecated.  Instead `__getitem__` should accept a slice object.  A slice object seems to have three attributes start, stop and step.

Comment: @neil yep that's what I ended up doing, but didn't realize that `__getslice__` is actually deprecated.  It seemed in my testing that `__getslice__` was called when I ran `a[-2:2]` (see bottom of my answer). Maybe because I'm using python 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subclass build-in list to provide default value when accessing list items:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, slice):
            step = item.step if item.step else 1
            return [self.__getitem__(i) for i in xrange(item.start, item.stop, step)]
        try:
            value = super(MyList, self).__getitem__(item)
        except IndexError:
            value = 0
        return value

    def __getslice__(self, start, stop):
        return self.__getitem__(slice(start, stop, None))
```

Example usage:

```
>> L = MyList([1,2,3,4])
>> L[0]
1
>> L[1]
2
>> L[2]
3
>> L[3]
4
>> L[4]
0
>> L[5]
0
>> L[0:6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 0]
```

Credit goes to [How to override the slice functionality of list in its derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16033017/how-to-override-the-slice-functionality-of-list-in-its-derived-class)

Comment: With this class MyList, do you know how to deal with ranges and have for example  `L[0:6]=[1,2,3,4,0,0]` ?

Comment: I've updated the answer. It's still a little bugy, but I hope you got the idea.

Comment: thanks a lot! It works for things like `L[0:6]=[1,2,3,4,0,0]`, but still not for `L[-2:6]` that should give `[0,0,1,2,3,4,0,0]`... I'm rather new into Python classes definition with slices, but I hope I can make it work :)

Answer (score 6):

You can convert `L` to dict:

```
In [1]: L=[1,2,3,4]

In [2]: D=dict([(x, y) for x, y in enumerate(L)])

In [3]: [D.get(i, 0) for i in xrange(-3, 5)]
Out[3]: [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0]
```

Comment: hum... `dict` seems to be the right data type for what I want... It it suited for large data amount (thousands of items) ?

Comment: Why not, a dict as built-in datatype is very fast.

Answer (score 1):

One of solve it problem is declare your own get function

```
def get(l, p):
   try:
       return l[p]
   except IndexError:
       return 0
```

ofc last line can be l.append(0) or something other

Comment: this won't work if I use negative index, but maybe I should add a `if p > 0` ?

Comment: Not always. This list have limited space? You know number of elements?

Comment: I want `get(l, p)=0` if p<0, thus maybe I would need to add a `if`

Comment: True. Its enough for this

Answer (score 1):

You can use a special get function:

```
def get(l, p):
    return l[p] if p >= 0 and p < len(l) else 0
```

Or even override the `__getitem__` method:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return super(MyList, self).__getitem__(index) if index >= 0 and index < len(self) else 0
```

Example:

```
>>> l2 = MyList([3, 5, 6, 8])
>>> l2[-1]
0
>>> l2[5]
0
>>> l2[2]
6
```

Comment: With your new class MyList, do you know how we could modify to be able to deal also with ranges like this `l2[-2:2]=[0,0,3,5,6]` ?

Comment: @Basj Python2 or Python3 ? I might have a solution but it appears to only work for Python3.

Comment: Also, would `[3, 5, 6]` instead of `[0,0,3,5,6]` be a good solution?

Comment: I use Python2. With your solution, `l2[-2:2]` gives `[]`. I would like `l2[-2:2]=[0,0,3,5,6]` (not [3,5,6]). Do you have an idea for this ?

Comment: I still cannot find how to be able to deal with such ranges... Do you have an idea ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `slice` objects, which are passed not to `__getslice__` but to `__getitem__` when using "extended slicing".  Then, move the `start` of the slice to `0`, and the `stop` to `len - 1` while keeping track.  Then add zeros:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if isinstance(item, slice):
            s, e = item.start, item.stop
            l = len(self) - 1
            left = -s if s < 0 else 0
            s = max(s, 0)
            right = e - l if e > l else 0
            e = min(e, l)
            return [0]*left + super(MyList, self).__getitem__(slice(s,e,item.step)) + [0]*right
        elif item < 0 or item >= len(self):
            return 0
        else:
            return super(MyList, self).__getitem__(item)
```

The catch is: you have to force your `getslice` call to send a `slice` object, which you can do in one of two ways.

```
>>> a[-2:2:1]   # the step = 1 is necessary
[0, 0, 1, 2]
```

or

```
>>> a[slice(-2,2)]
[0, 0, 1, 2]
```

Works on both ends:

```
>>> a[-2:6:1]
[0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 0]
```

---

#### Original attempt

If `__getslice__` was passed the actual arguments given by `a[-2:2]`, then this would work:

```
class MyList(list):
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        if item < 0 or item >= len(self):
            return 0
        return super(MyList, self).__getitem__(item)

    def __getslice__(self, s, e):
        print "input: ", s, e
        l = len(self) - 1
        left = -s if s < 0 else 0
        s = max(s, 0)
        right = e - l if e > l else 0
        e = min(e, l)

        return [0]*left + super(MyList, self).__getslice__(s,e) + [0]*right
```

But for some reason, `a[-2:2]` calls `a.__getslice(2,2)` with both values positive.

```
>>> a[-2:2]
input: 2 2
```

Comment: interesting, we are close to the result !

Comment: I think I'm making progress, actually, using a slice object.  brb :)

Comment: OK it works now.  Mutability of these lists might not behave correctly (as in, `b = a[-2:2:1]; b[0] = 88` might not do what you want it to do.  But that's a tougher problem.  Also note that I tested this in python 2.

Comment: Great ! So it doesn't work with `a[-2:2]`, we really need the `a[-2:2:1]` ?

Comment: Yes, in my testing, because `a[-2:2]` is equivalent to `a.__getslice__(2,2)` and kills the negative.  Perhaps this is different in python 3 (I tested with 2).

Comment: I've checked in 3.3 and `__getitem__` is always called.

Comment: @neil In that case, it would be easier to do in python 3, but [@Basj is using python 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20217843/zero-outside-the-range-of-a-list-array/20220772?noredirect=1#comment30149972_20218104), so this will have to do.

Answer (score 0):

Random indexes out of list len work only for slices. If you want to get (or set) certain objects you must use indexes only in list range.
So

```
L[4]=0
x=L[4]
```

does not work, but

```
L[4:6]=0,0 or L[4:6]=[0,0]
x,y=L[2:10000] # x=3,y=4
```

will work